# Visual Studio - WPF - Added reference to DLL, Added namespace, cannot find usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

This problem is frustrating me to no end.

I downloaded the demo/sample project from the source, loaded it into Visual Studio, and run it  just fine.  The references, namespaces, and everything are all working.

So, I decided to add the reference and appropriate assembly namespaces to my own project to incorporate the open-source solution into it.

It won't work: I keep getting "The name Gauge does not exist within the namespace"

I got so frustrated I copied the code from the source code identically into my project.  It still won't work.  I have tested the demo/sample project on both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013, and it works.

What am I doing wrong when I import this thing?

Here's the code that simultaneously works and doesn't work:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfGauge.Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="win"
        Width="825" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        xmlns:g="clr-namespace:WpfGauge;assembly=WpfGauge">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <g:Gauge DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                     Height="300" 
                     Width="300"
                     AutoScale="True" 
                     MinValue="2" 
                     MaxValue="12" 
                     ValueFormat=" {}{0} rph" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the C# code:

```
using System.Windows;
using WpfGauge;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System;

namespace WpfGauge.Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public readonly DependencyProperty RunsPerHourProperty =
                        DependencyProperty.Register("RunsPerHour", 
                        typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));

        public double RunsPerHour
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(RunsPerHourProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(RunsPerHourProperty, value); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += (args, e) =>
                {
                    RunsPerHour = (double)DateTime.Now.Second;
                };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I am at my wit's end with this thing...

Comment: Have you tried cleaning then rebuilding the solution(s) yet?

Comment: I think you needle to add the xmlns-namespace in your xaml. This must be g.

Comment: So where is your code for Gauge? From what you posted, it might well not exist.

Comment: Brian: Yes. Many times.  Tomtom: I did - last line of the <Window> definition   nvoigt: "Add a reference" implies I referenced a dll containing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As evident from the error **`Gauge` class is not getting resolved by XAML file**.

Here is the namespace which you must have copy/pasted:

```
xmlns:g="clr-namespace:WpfGauge;assembly=WpfGauge"
```

I guess in your case Gauge namespace exist under `WpfGauge.Test`. Also, if this XAML file and Gauge class exist in same assembly(project), you can omit assembly path altogether.

```
xmlns:g="clr-namespace:WpfGauge.Test
```

But in case assembly is different, it should be like this:

```
xmlns:g="clr-namespace:NameSpaceOfGaugeClass;assembly=AssemblyNameOfGaugeClass"
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because it is accurate; though it didn't actually solve the problem in my specific case.  I don't know exactly what I did, short of closing Visual Studio and re-opening it multiple times, but it is now working.  Who knows...?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to drag drop the actual DLL into the toolbox. I do it all the time. open the folder where the user Control file is (bin\debug) more than likely, then drag the DLL over the general section of the toolbox in the IDE.